# How can we get IBM Cloud "SDK for NodeJS" logs to Activity Tracker with LogDNA?

Tags: ibm-cloud, logdna

we have running applications on nodeJS and want to integrate the Logs into our activity tracker with logDNA. how can we implement this?

Comment: Integrate logs into the Activity Tracker or Log Monitoring (with LogDNA)? There are instructions for the monitoring: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/Log-Analysis-with-LogDNA?topic=LogDNA-ingest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The activity tracker is for the ibm cloud to write records of the stuff it does on your behalf

From https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/Activity-Tracker-with-LogDNA?topic=logdnaat-getting-started#getting-started

> IBM Cloud Activity Tracker with LogDNA collects and stores audit records for API calls made to resources that run in the IBM Cloud.

You can not contribute arbitrary content to the activity tracker.

You can log into logdna, see https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/Log-Analysis-with-LogDNA?topic=LogDNA-ingest

Comment: can you share more details about the ingest of logs from IBM's "SDK for NodeJS" to "Log-Analysis-with-LogDNA"?

Comment: I'm working some content for this topic.  Some questions:
- Are you using cloud foundry?  
- Are you expecting some nodeJS logging without writing logging code in the app?
- Are you planning on writing logging code in the nodeJS application?